# How to Notify the Owner that Data has been inserted in Firebase using Angular 2 Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Project and new users and also data is added to the database in realtime.
I want to get notified when anything changes on the database or a new user is added .

How do we acheive such a thing in Angular .

I tried googling but coudn't find any , i simply want a mail from firebase to me saying data changed or user added.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is a great use case for Cloud Functions for Firebase.

You can write functions that trigger when data is added to the database and when a new user is authenticated for the first time.  Here are some resources to find out more:

[Cloud Functions for Firebase Usage Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

[Cloud Functions for Firebase samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)

[Getting Started with Cloud Functions for Firebase - Firecasts](https://youtu.be/EvV9Vk9iOCQ)

[Database Triggers with Cloud Functions for Firebase - Firecasts](https://youtu.be/7E13ZBCyKT0)

[Authentication Triggers with Cloud Functions for Firebase - Firecats](https://youtu.be/pADTJA3BoxE?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM)

The Cloud Functions for Firebase samples are especially useful because they include how to send emails using Nodemailer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Taking Jen's answer a bit more forward .

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
// For Gmail, enable these:
// 1. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
// 2. https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
// For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
// TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
const gmailEmail = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.email);
const gmailPassword = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.password);
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
    `smtps://${gmailEmail}:${gmailPassword}@smtp.gmail.com`);

// Your company name to include in the emails
// TODO: Change this to your app or company name to customize the email sent.
const APP_NAME = 'Cloud Storage for Firebase quickstart';

// [START sendWelcomeEmail]
/**
 * Sends a welcome email to new user.
 */
// [START onCreateTrigger]
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
// [END onCreateTrigger]
  // [START eventAttributes]
  const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.

  const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
  const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.
  // [END eventAttributes]

  return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
});
// [END sendWelcomeEmail]


// Sends a welcome email to the given user.
function sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${APP_NAME} <noreply@firebase.com>`,
    to: email
  };

  // The user subscribed to the newsletter.
  mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
  mailOptions.text = `Hey ${displayName || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. I hope you will enjoy our service.`;
  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
  });
}
```

For more Info check this [Firebase](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/firebase)